# Hudson Do not increment Build Number for failed builds

Tags: build, hudson, build-process

I would like to stop hudson from incrementing the build number for failed builds.  I see no value in incrementing the build number for failed builds as they are not usable.

I expect this is a simple setting in the config but cannot find it and I can't find a solution on SO.

Could someone please let me know if this is possible?

Comment: What build system are you using (Make, ant, bash, maven...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A build is a build, whether it's successful or failed, isn't it?  Build number is different from release number, or version number, or whatever your organization calls it.

Additionally, Hudson stores the entire logs from all builds so you can easily refer back to them.  This aids you in your ability to go fix the problems with broken builds.  If you didn't have that, and you had multiple broken builds in a row, how could you tell what the problem was with each of the builds?

IMHO, you can't find a solution because it's something both that you shouldn't be doing, and cannot currently be done.

Comment: Mike is right on the point..."Build number is different from release number, or version number". When you refer back to your team about the failed build how are you going to communicate? "There was an issue in today's 9.36AM failed build which was fixed in Build No:222 but we are seeing it again in 11:22AM failed build". If some one want to fix the issue first thing he\she would be doing is do the root cause analysis looking at the failed builds. My 2 cents.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your trying to automate a rolling minor release #. As others have mentioned you shouldn't use the hudson build number.

If you are using **Maven** you can use the release plugin so that the least significant version number is bumped (ie 1.0.x where x is incremented) on successful builds.

The [Maven release plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/) will also checkin the new version # into source control (using wagon) and create a tag.

If you are not using Maven I'm sure there are other build tools that do something similar.